# Passing pointer to uint16_t to subroutine that expects uint8_t[] array in C - how to?

Tags: c

I have a subroutine which expects two arguments: uint8_t[] array buffer and uint16_t size:
`void getData(uint8_t * pData, uint16_t size)`
Instead of 2-byte array pointer I would like to pass a pointer to uint16_t variable so I do not have to convert array content to uint16_t variable later on. Here is what I tried:

```
uint16_t value;
uint8_t values[2];
// instead of:
getData(values, 2);
value = (values[0] << 8) | values[1];
// I want to simply call:
getData((uint8_t *)&value, 2);
```

The above approach does not yield the expected result. What is the correct way?
Please advise.

Comment: The result will depend on your machine's endianness. What you wrote corresponds to big-endian but you're most likely on a little-endian architecture.

Comment: Most CPUs are little-endian these days (which means the lowest significant byte comes first). Your calculation of `value` swaps the bytes.

Comment: Can you explain what your issue is with the code you want something instead of? It looks *much* better than the horrible cast that you say you want.

Comment: As always it would help if you gave us the input and the expected output/outcome.

Comment: Also, if you don't follow eerorika's advice then use the htons/ntohs functions ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-ntohs) the Windows documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions of code are endian dependant. If you assume that it always would be working on little-endian machine, the original approach works. On big endian platform the second approach works because memory setup for a multi-byte value  matches mathematical notation.

There is reason of simplicity why big-endian order is used to communicate over network and various hardware interfaces.

Many platforms include "endian.h" header which can contain macro definitions to detect whether your CPU  or memory controller are big-endian, little-endian, or "middle-endian" (variable or unusual order).

FOr crossing line between Microsoft compilers whichhave that definition in "winsock.h" and POSIX-compatible compilers, I tend to use following snippet:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>   // or appropriate winsockX.h
#   ifndef __LITTLE_ENDIAN
#       define __LITTLE_ENDIAN 1234
#   endif
#   ifndef __BYTE_ORDER
#       define __BYTE_ORDER __LITTLE_ENDIAN
#   endif
#else
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <endian.h>
#   if __BYTE_ORDER != __LITTLE_ENDIAN
#       if __BYTE_ORDER != __BIG_ENDIAN
#           define __UNKNOWN_ENDIAN
#       endif
#   endif
#endif
```

And then I would use __BYTE_ORDER for something like following, but likely wrapped up by some sort of function as "implementation details".

```
#if ((__BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN)) 
  getData(values, 2);
  value = (values[0] << 8) | values[1];

#else
  getData((uint8_t *)&value, 2);
#endif
```

Comment: The first version isn't dependent on endianness of the system. It works on big endian systems exactly the same as on little endian systems. There's no need for two versions.

Comment: @eerorika And I'd like to invite readers to mull over that fact long enough to actually understand it, because it is related to the core rationales and concepts of C: The abstraction from the hardware representation makes programs portable, one of the goals of C. The key insight is that the bit shift operator is a *logical, semantic* shift. The left shift is not necessarily a shift towards smaller addresses: We don't know which way it shifts, and we don't want to know. The *compiler* knows, and does the right thing. 0x1234 may well be '{0x34, 0x12}` in memory; or not.

Comment: Exactly, endianness is the problem here. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> getData((uint8_t *)&value, 2);
> ```
>
> The above approach does not yield the expected result.

The problem is that different computer systems use different order for multi-byte integers. Your first example interprets the data as most significant byte in the lowest address and least significant byte in the highest address. This is known as "big endian" byte order (big end first).

If your second attempt produced a different result, then we can deduce that your system uses the other order, "little endian". This is in fact, quite typical. For example, the x86 CPU architecture uses little endian byte order.

> What is the correct way?

The correct and portable way to interpret a sequence of bytes as big endian integer is the one that you didn't want to do:

> ```
> // instead of:
> getData(values, 2);
> value = (values[0] << 8) | values[1];
> ```

The way that you want to do is correct only for interpreting sequence of bytes as an integer in the "native" byte order. That's a different operation on systems where the native byte order isn't big endian. This operation behaves differently on systems of different endianness and is thus not portable.

Comment: Thank you for all the kind answers. Indeed, endianness is the reason my intended approach does not work. I did not think about it.